# Open connection with Signal R to database ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

My use case is: I have a form that sends a picture and some info to the database (it can be send either by anonymous users or logged in) but only admins who are responsible for this can see them. So my question is can it be done with SignalR this real time taking information from DB whenever there is a new valid entry saved in the table, the admins that are responsible for this will get a notification message? (something like an open listening channel to DB)
If its not possible i'll appreciate any suggestions corrections.
Thanks for your time

Comment: @S.Minechev Does the admin is always on this page? If yes signalr is an option. It depends on your requirements. For example do you need only once a day a message that there are new pictures, or do you need for every picture? Send a mail can also be an option if you only need a notification once a day for example

Comment: The admin has a page which contains all the forms which are not seen. If it goes there will see the new ones, but i want whenever there is new send form to appears message on admin menu so he will know that there is a new form instead of staying there and refresh the page every time. I don't know if its clear enough ?

Comment: @S.Minechev: I did once something similar with signalr. I did an admin page where the admin can see which users are logged in. So at the start the client (of the admin) asks server which user are logged in. The server returns a collection with active users. After that the server sends a message to the clients in the case a new user has logged in. This works perfect with signalr. You can go this way. For details about signalr read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server